# Best Event-Driven Diagram

Tags: uml, event-driven-design

with the OOP the software design can be easly described with a class diagram. But with the event-driven programming the class diagram is not very suitable. What is (if exists) the best description diagram for this different approach?

Comment: UML isn't about class diagrams. Describing a model involves static and dynamic parts, both covered by UML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML offers state machine and protocol state machine diagrams. In addition, UML offers signal receptions within activity diagrams.